# How to stretch div height to fill parent div - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a page with `div`s like shown in the layout / screenshot below:

[image: layout]

The code is here:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#B,
#C,
#D {
  position: absolute;
}

#A {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #99CC00;
}

#B {
  top: 35px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 35px;
  background-color: #999999;
  z-index: 100;
  border: solid 4px #00CC00;
}

#B2 {
  margin-top: -35px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#B1 {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: #CC0066;
}

#C {
  top: 35px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 35px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#D {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #3399FF;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="A">A</div>
  <div id="B">
    <div id="B1">B1</div>
    <div id="B2">B2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="C">C</div>
  <div id="D">D</div>
</div>
```

I want to adjust the height of B2 `div` to fill (or stretch to) entire B `div` (marked with a green border in the image) and don't want to cross the footer D `div`. Here is a working fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/QWDxr/3683/)(updated). How can I solve this??

Comment: why you have B1, what is the use of it?

Answer (score 60):

Suppose you have

```html
<body>
  <div id="root" />
</body>
```

With normal CSS, you can do the following. See a working app https://github.com/onmyway133/Lyrics/blob/master/index.html

```css
#root {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

With flexbox, you can

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#root {
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: I just realized this won't work anymore if you add `height: 100%` to #root. Can somebody explain this?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048470/how-to-fill-vertical-space-with-flexbox

Answer (score 14):

http://jsfiddle.net/QWDxr/1/

Use the "min-height" property
Be wary of paddings, margins and borders :)

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#B, #C, #D {
    position: absolute;
}
#A{
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #99CC00;
}
#B {
    top: 35px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 35px;
    background-color: #999999;
    z-index:100;
}
#B2 {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -35px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#B1 {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: #CC0066;
}
#C {
    top: 35px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 35px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#D {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
```

Comment: no.. it fill entire page with a top margin. i just want to fill the specific div `B`

Comment: It works correctly in chrome and firefox. If this doesn't work for you, you can use [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Comment: it works, but it is cutting the footer `div id= D`. I dont want it to cross div d

Comment: `height:100%` is missing a semicolon for the `#B2` style.

Comment: Worked for me inside a custom navbar.

Answer (score 5):

If you're gonna use B2 for styling purposes you can try this "hack"

```
#B { overflow: hidden;}
#B2 {padding-bottom: 9999px; margin-bottom: -9999px}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWDxr/3/)

Comment: This works, thanks. By the way, it should be `margin-bottom: -9999px;`. You're missing the minus.

Answer (score 4):

What suited my purpose was to create a div that was always bounded within the overall browser window by a fixed amount.

What worked, at least on firefox, was this

`<div style="position: absolute; top: 127px; left: 75px;right: 75px; bottom: 50px;">`

Insofar as the actual window is not forced into scrolling, the div preserves its boundaries to the window edge during all re-sizing.

Hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 1):

B2 container **position relative**

Top position B2 + of remaining height

Height of B2 + height B1 or remaining height

Comment: Setting the parent node to position relative solved my unrelated problem!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, you can do this:

```
<body onload="$('nav').height($('main').height());">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always noticed this is possible with tables, so just change your div display types to table types and it works.

To control width:
Set container div to display:table (or inline-table) and inside divs to display:table-cell like this:

```
<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table;'>
  <div style='background-color: red; width: 50%; height: 100%; display: table-cell;'>
    Left Side
  </div>
  <div style='background-color: green; height: 100%; display: table-cell;'>
    Right Side<br>
    <div style='background-color: blue; width = 100%;'>
      This is 100% of remainder!
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above will have the left div is 50% and the right inner div will fill the remainder.  You can even place another div in the right inner with 100% width and it will fill the remainder.

To control height you just use table-row instead of table-cell:

```
<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table;'>
  <div style='background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table;'>
    <div style='background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 20%; display: table-row;'>
      Top Side
    </div>
    <div style='background-color: green; height: 100%; display: table-row;'>
      Bottom Side<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No positioning or flexing which usually causes other unwanted side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found another solution, which is to position everything absolutely and then use {top:0; bottom:0}.

```css
#B {
   position:absolute;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: orange;
}
#B1 {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: cyan;   
}
#B2 {
   position:absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 35px;
   width: 100%;
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="B">
   <div id="B1">B1</div>
   <div id="B2">B2</div>
</div>
```

Note that there is some overlapping.