# How to fill vertical space with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If `.right` item stretch height to any size, how to make `.item` elements inside `.left` to fill vertical space equally?

From:
[image]

To: 
[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
}

.left {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="item">
      Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d7o58kaj/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`align-content: stretch`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276).

That means that flex lines will equally share all available space in the container along the [**cross axis**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276). (A similar effect to `flex: 1` on all items on the main axis.)

However, when you define a height for a flex item *when the cross axis is vertical*, or width, *when the cross axis is horizontal*, you override the `align-content` default.

In your row-direction container, the cross axis is vertical. So if you remove `height: 100%`, that allows `align-content: stretch` to work.

Learn more about flex alignment on the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment on the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
}

.left {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;      /* <--- this brings align-content into play */
  /* flex-direction: row;  <--- default setting; can be omitted */
  /* align-items: stretch; <--- default setting; can be omitted */
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Removed `height: 100%` from `.left`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
}

.left {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="item">
      Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain why this works, as just drop a code is pretty useless

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex property

```
align-items: stretch ;
```

for achieving this.