# div under the navbar with 100% width shows scrollbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hey guys I hope you are doing fine, so I was working on a page. mainly with a navbar and below that navbar a bootstrap grid and a footer.. so I want to display the page, as the grid between the navbar and footer covers the space between em, for that I used the width 100% for the row but it dosent seems to work. this is my code.
so it becomes a single page for every device. without the scrollbar

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light main_nav">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                <div class="logo mr-auto">
                    <img class="navbar-brand" src="images/michatroom.png" width="150">
                </div>
            </nav>
    <!-- NAVBAR END -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row my_row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                www
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                www
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                www
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-bottom navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed bottom</a>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

My Css :

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
.main_nav {
    background: #006080;
}
.logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.my_row > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.my_row {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581799/how-to-stretch-div-height-to-fill-parent-div-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add overflow:hidden to body for css

```css
body{
overflow:hidden;
}

* { margin:0; padding:0; }
.main_nav {
    background: #006080;
}
.logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.my_row > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.my_row {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light main_nav">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                <div class="logo mr-auto">
                    <img class="navbar-brand" src="images/michatroom.png" >
                </div>
            </nav>
    <!-- NAVBAR END -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row my_row">
            <div class="col-md-2" style='width:20%'>
                www
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8" style='width:60%'>
                www
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style='width:20%'>
                www
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-bottom navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed bottom</a>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works but some of the part is being covered with the footer